# Cannot write the output of the reducer to a sequence file

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, sequencefile

I have a Map function and a Reduce function outputting kep-value pairs of class Text and IntWritable..
This is just the gist of the Map part in the Main function :

```
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
  tablename,        // input HBase table name
  scan,             // Scan instance to control CF and attribute selection
  AnalyzeMapper.class,   // mapper
  Text.class,             // mapper output key
  IntWritable.class,             // mapper output value
  job);
```

And here's my Reducer part in the Main function which writes the output to HDFS

```
job.setReducerClass(AnalyzeReducerFile.class);
job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://localhost:54310/output_file"));
```

How do i make the reducer write to a [Sequence File](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile.html) instead?

I've tried the following code but doesn't work

```
job.setReducerClass(AnalyzeReducerFile.class);
job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
SequenceFileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://localhost:54310/sequenceOutput"));
```

Edit: here is the output message i get when i run

```
WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException: No lease on /sequenceOutput/_temporary/_attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0/part-r-00000 File does not exist. Holder DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-79044441_1 does not have any open files.
13/07/29 17:04:20 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for block null bad datanode[0] nodes == null
13/07/29 17:04:20 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Could not get block locations. Source file "/sequenceOutput/_temporary/_attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0/part-r-00000" - Aborting...
13/07/29 17:04:20 ERROR hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to close file /sequenceOutput/_temporary/_attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0/part-r-00000
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it doesn't work (it looks correct). Is there an error message? Does the folder `sequenceOutput` get created with data in it>

Comment: @ChrisWhite I have updated the question with the error message.

Comment: @Pavan Maybe it is due to some issue in transporting data from the datanode. [Check these links](http://goo.gl/v5iBTk)

Comment: Why do we need to specify setOutputPath twice ?